# How do I import changing/dynamic data on a webpage?

Tags: import, web-access, input-devices

A remote device (sensor) is sending measurements (that I get in JSON format) to a given URL and is sending new measurements (data points) every couple of minutes. I cannot share the URL but the originating sensor is an air quality sensor (see https://www.purpleair.com/map?589048#11/18.0825/-67.039, as an example; note that the data I am getting is NOT the same as this example).
Here is an example of data that I am getting at the URL:

Received events:
{"dewpoint":11.11,"pm2.5_A_outside":60.09,"lon":-122.012161,"pm10.0_B_outside":13.12,"pm2.5_B_outside":7.38,"pm10.0_A_outside":61.73,"sensorType":"2.0+OPENLOG+15802 MB+DS3231+BME280+PMSX003-B+PMSX003-A","temperature":18.89,"humidity":60.0,"pm10.0_B_inside":13.12,"pm10.0_A_inside":54.8,"firmwareVersion":"4.02","lat":37.375938,"timestamp":"2019-07-15T06:57:18.000+0000","pm1.0_A_inside":37.11,"pm1.0_B_inside":4.77,"statementName":"PurpleAirStatement","rssi":-50.0,"pm1.0_B_outside":4.77,"pressure":1017.13,"pm1.0_A_outside":56.42,"SID":"71b6b542-d75c-4b8e-b947-fc6603496b78","uptime":null,"_headers":null,"macAddress":"84:f3:eb:6e:b3:c4","pm2.5_B_inside":7.38,"pm2.5_A_inside":45.58}

A new record (like this one) is added to the bottom every 2 minutes or so

How do I import this streaming data into Mathematica. Here is the output I get from URLExecute[url]:

```
Websocket not connected - no realtime data will be shown! 

Websocket connected 
 Realtime data  


Received events: 

{{message}}
```

On the webpage after "Received events" data starts to come in (as in the example above), but i don't know how to capture it

Comment: Can you provide an URL that behaves the way your server does? Can you share the code you are using to connect, including your `URLExecute` call? Put yourself in the position of somebody trying to help you. What information would you need to **reproduce your problem and find a solution**? That, **YOU** should provide in the question. Please [edit] your question and add more context.

Comment: And BTW, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question. As I indicated, I am not able to share the URL but hopefully the additional info is useful in providing an answer.